# nVidia graphics: Virtual Console not showing

Tags: debian, console, display-driver, nvidia

After a fresh install of Debian 12 "Bookworm" (using KDE Plasma), I installed the propriatary nVidia drivers:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver
```

After the following reboot, I tried to log in from SDDM and was only greeted by a mostly black screen with the last boot messages frozen.

Switching to virtual consoles (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>...) seemed to be impossible as well. Always the same screen with the boot messages.

Rebooting the computer multiple times showed this behavior each time.

After I switched from Wayland to X11, I was able to successfully log into Plasma and it worked. But switching to the virtual consoles still only show the aforementioned screen.

I checked with

```
systemctl list-units | grep getty
```

and the consoles were `loaded active running`.

My assumption is now, that the consoles are working fine, but the graphics adapter has the last low-resolution screen saved in the buffer and does not refresh, thus onlyy showing the last thing showed during boot.

Before installing `nvidia-driver` I used the nouveau driver and the virtual consoles were showing normally.

Is there a way to get the virtual consoles working/displayed again?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and solved it by using the older 470.199 driver, which is packaged for Debian 12 as `nvidia-tesla-470-driver`. My GPU is a Quadro K2200 with 640 cuda cores and 4 GiB memory, first released in 2014.

Note this solution has only been tested for X11 sessions, not for Wayland sessions. Try this solution only if `nvidia-detect` reports that your GPU is compatible with the nvidia tesla 470 driver series.

After installing the `nvidia-tesla-470-driver` package, remove and purge (i.e. `apt-get remove --purge`) the `nvidia-driver` and `nvidia-kernel-support` packages. Reboot, and the "NVIDIA X Server Settings" gui application should show that you are using the tesla-470 driver. At that point you should be able to switch to a virtual terminal with the usual `ctl-alt-Fn` key combination.

I don't see that this issue has been widely reported, so it may only be a problem with older GPU's, or certain specific models. None of the usual recommended solutions involving GRUB settings were helpful for me while using the 525 driver, and none were necessary while using the 470 driver.

Comment: I switched graphics cards in the meantime, so I cannot test, if your solution would solve my issue. I switched to an AMD card and using the most recent driver bundled with Debian worked flawlessly out of the box with Wayland and X11.